# how to access drawable pairs in hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap

I try access to drawable resource that I put in hashmap object
this is my relevant code:

```
  private void pairImagesCollection() {
    mImages.put(R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img1shadow);
    mImages.put(R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img2shadow);
    mImages.put(R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img3shadow);
    mImages.put(R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img4shadow);
}

 private void checkMatch(View dragView, View view) {
        ImageView target = (ImageView) view;
        ImageView dragged = (ImageView) dragView;
        Drawable image = dragged.getDrawable();
        int imgId = mImages.get(Integer.valueOf(image)); // wrong, I don't know how to do it ?!
        target.setImageResource(imgId);
    }
```

Any help will be appraised!

Comment: why you are passing `drawable` object to `valueOf()` , it accepts `String` to convert it into `int`?

Comment: @Prashant No, no String, I thought that R.drawable is unique and I can to retrieve a desired image by that via imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> int imgId = mImages.get(Integer.valueOf(image));

You cannot get `Resource/Drawable Id` from `ImageView` through `Drawable`. With codes above, You can set tag for  `ImageView dragged`. After that get value with with your `mImages`.

Before you `checkMatch`, you set tag for dragView as Drawble, something like that:

```
dragged.setTag(R.drawable.img1);
```

And now you can  `getDrawableId` and

```
imgId = getDrawableId(dragged);

    private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) {
        return (Integer) iv.getTag();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)**

```
Iterator itObj = hashMapOBJ.entrySet().iterator();
                        while (itObj .hasNext()) {
                            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) itObj.next();

                                String Key = (String) pair.getKey();
                                Drawable Value = (Drawable) pair.getValue();
                                hashMapOBJ.put(Key, Value);
                                System.out.println("Key: " + Key + "------>" + Value);

                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a hashmap that stores references to an image and its shadow right?
Which image you want to put on the image view? You have to iterate through your map and put the image you want:

```
Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
         }
```

If you want to put the value image then you put the **pair.getKey()** else you put the **pair.getValue()**.

```
target.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```